# Triggering click on <el-select> doesn't change v-model

Tags: vuejs2, jestjs, vue-test-utils, element-ui

Im having trouble trying to trigger click events on Element UI components. I try to click the el-select to open the dropdown menu, and click on an option, but the initial value declared on the initial props never changes. It always returns *common.ativos_inativos*

Can someone give me a light ?

**test:**

```
it('Erro no vue-test-utils clicar na lista de opções do select não funciona', async () => {
  t.initWrapper({
    propsData: {
      value: ''
    }
  })
  await t.wrapper.find('#SelectAtivoInativo').trigger('click')
  await t.wrapper.vm.$nextTick()
  await t.wrapper.findAll('.el-select-dropdown__item').at(1).trigger('click')
  await t.wrapper.vm.$nextTick()

  expect(t.wrapper.find('#SelectAtivoInativo').element.value).toBe('common.ativo')
})
```

**Vue component:**

```
<template>
  <el-select
    id="SelectAtivoInativo"
    :value="value"
    :readonly="readonly"
    :disabled="_disabled"
    @input="input"
    @change="change"
  >
    <el-option
      :label="$t('common.ativos_inativos')"
      value=""
    />
    <el-option
      :label="$t('common.ativo')"
      value="1"
    />
    <el-option
      :label="$t('common.inativo')"
      value="0"
    />
  </el-select>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your markup the value of `#SelectAtivoInativo` when`('.el-select-dropdown__item').at(1)` is selected should be `1`. `common.inativo` is the label not the value of your option.

The following should pass:

```
expect(t.wrapper.find('#SelectAtivoInativo').element.value).toBe('1')
```